# How to translate Promise code to async await

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I have some simple Promise in js:

```js
 let link = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1";            
             
 fetch(link)
      .then(response => response.json())  
      .then(data => console.log(data))         
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

... and I want to translate it to 'async await' like here:

```js
  const API_ENDPOINT = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';

  const fetchUsers = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(API_ENDPOINT);
  const data = await response.json();  
  };
```

... but I don't know how involve it in 'async await' correctly. This involving gives error:

```
fetchUsers()
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then (data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.error(`ERROR ${error}`));
```

Can you help me fix this error?

Comment: *What* error does it give?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to call `.json()` twice in a row now

Answer (score 0):

```
 const API_ENDPOINT = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';

  const fetchUsers = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(API_ENDPOINT);
    const data = await response.json();  
    console.log(data);
  };
```

Your code is working prefectly Just call fetchUsers() and It will print data through this line  `console.log(data);`

You can't use await keyword outside the `async` type function

Read this -

> An async function can contain an await expression that pauses the
>   execution of the async function and waits for the passed Promise's
>   resolution, and then resumes the async function's execution and
>   returns the resolved value.
>
> Remember, the await keyword is only valid inside async functions. If
>   you use it outside of an async function's body, you will get a
>   SyntaxError.

Answer (score 0):

Async functions must be functions. So, you need to create a function to do that.
MDN says:

> The async function declaration defines an asynchronous function, which returns an AsyncFunction object.

Read more about that on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

So:

1. Create a function using the `async` keyword
2. Perform your `fetch` call *inside* the function using the `await` keyword
3. Perform any other operations inside your function using the `await` keyword around any promise related operations (if you want)

An example below:

```
async function doFetch(link) {
    let result = await fetch(link); // this will wait the result to be fetched
    console.log(result); // this will only log the result of the fetch promise after it is resolved
    let json = await result.json();
    console.log(json);
}
const link = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
doFetch(link);
```

Also, remember that when you use the `await` keyword, your asynchronous code will actually run synchronously, so, two sequential calls to any promises will run synchronously, like so:

```
async function foo() {
    let bar = await fetch('https://www.google.com');

    // the line below will run just _*AFTER*_ the above line is completely resolved
    let baz = await fetch('https://www.facebook.com');
}
```

Comment: I presume you mean `async function foo()`, not `await function foo()`.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems here;

1. You don't return anything from your async function
2. You apply `response.json()` twice.

Just corect the code as;

```
const API_ENDPOINT = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1',
      fetchUsers   = async () => { var response = await fetch(API_ENDPOINT);
                                   return await response.json();
                                 };
fetchUsers().then (data => console.log(data))
            .catch(error => console.error(`ERROR ${error}`));
```